# Should we allow soft-questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Recently, a few questions have been popping up around the site, such as people wanting to try Blender, looking to fit it into their workflow etc. In short, these type of questions don't carry *definitive answers* so people are free to interpret these as they wish. The most recent being [Is Blender the right program for me](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5105/is-blender-the-right-program-for-me).

A soft-question is basically:

> Questions that don't admit a definitive answer.

Should we allow these in our scope?

Answer (score 8):

It depends on the scope of the question. If the question includes specifics (Eg: Can I integrate Blender into a workflow that includes GIMP and Inkscape?), then it's fine. If however, the question is broad (Eg: "Is Blender right for me?: Is it as easy to use as Fancy3D 10.30"), we would be better off closing it as NARQ.

Comment: Said question _"Is Blender right for me"._ is specific somehwat, OP is asking if it suitable enough an _animation_ package for what he intends to do. Off-topic as it doesn't have a definitive answer but borderline acceptable since he is asking about Blender's features.

Comment: I think we will have to see how the community reacts to these first but I can definitely see more of these questions coming in the future.

Comment: I like the idea of distinguishing between soft specific questions, and soft open questions. I think it's entirely appropriate to answer questions like "How does development time compare between Cycles and BI?" This helps the community learn something specific. But we should be careful to avoid questions like "Is Cycles better than BI," which is non-specific and qualitative.

Comment: [One older question along these lines](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3748/599). Also IMO "Can I integrate Blender into a workflow that includes GIMP and Inkscape?" is not so much a soft question as an  external applications question.

Comment: @gandalf3 I'll clarify what I mean.

Answer (score 5):

I see no problem in allowing these provided that they are made [*Community Wiki*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) and ask for something specific.

Many other sites on the network have some policy for these types of questions and it could work well for us as well.